# How to implement TLS-ALPN in .NET C# for a HTTP/2 server

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, http2, alpn

does anyone know, how I can implement the [TLS-ALPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Layer_Protocol_Negotiation) in .NET?

I've implemented a basic HTTP/2 server, but without TLS encryption.
I searched in google, but I only found resources for C, Java or other languages, but nothing for .NET (C#)

Comment: any luck on this? :)

Comment: not really.
I've tried to extract the relevant code from https://github.com/MSOpenTech/http2-katana, but still getting an exception, when I try to connect over https.

Answer (score 2):

According to [HttpTwo](https://github.com/Redth/HttpTwo) project on Github it is not possible currently because of a bug.

Update: It's not supported in .NET. You can vote for it here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/6264363-add-support-for-alpn-to-system-net-security-sslstr

quote:

> The HTTP/2 RFC states that secure connections must use ALPN to
>   negotiate the protocol. Unfortunately, .NET's SslStream has no ability
>   to specify application protocols as part of the TLS authentication, so
>   it can't support ALPN. There's an [issue tracking this on
>   dotnetfix](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4721) however it seems like this isn't going to happen very
>   soon (especially on mono and .NET 4.x).

Answer (score 2):

It actually is possible. With some reflection you can inject any extension in client or server hello.

Here's some code to give you an idea:

```
// Refer IANA on ApplicationProtocols: https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-extensiontype-values/tls-extensiontype-values.xhtml#alpn-protocol-ids
public static void FixALPN(params string[] protocols) {
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref cntFixALPN) > 1)
    {
        throw new Exception("FixALPN should be called only ONCE, put it in your Main or use a static constructor.");
        return;
    }

    // get the needed (internal) System types
    string tpname = typeof(System.Net.HttpListener).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    Type tpiface = Type.GetType(tpname.Replace("HttpListener", "SSPIInterface"));
    Type tpgsspi = Type.GetType(tpname.Replace("HttpListener", "GlobalSSPI"));
    Type tpsdc = Type.GetType(tpname.Replace("HttpListener", "SafeDeleteContext"));
    Type tpsecbuf = Type.GetType(tpname.Replace("HttpListener", "SecurityBuffer"));

    // create ALPN buffer
    ConstructorInfo ci = (from x in tpsecbuf.GetConstructors() where x.GetParameters().Length == 4 select x).First();
    var secbufempty = ci.Invoke(new object[] { new byte[0], 0, 0, 0 });
    byte[] btsalpn = GetALPNBuffer(protocols);
    var secbufalpn = ci.Invoke(new object[] { btsalpn, 0, btsalpn.Length, 18 });

    // grab the object to replace...
    FieldInfo fi = tpgsspi.GetField("SSPISecureChannel", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    var secchan = fi.GetValue(null);

    // ...and the method(s) we'll use in our intercepted call(s)
    MethodInfo miSDC_ISC = tpsdc.GetMethod("InitializeSecurityContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    MethodInfo miSDC_ASC = tpsdc.GetMethod("AcceptSecurityContext", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    // fake the internal interface
    var result = new InterfaceImplementer(tpiface, (mcm) => {
        MethodInfo mi = (MethodInfo)mcm.MethodBase;
        object[] args = mcm.Args;
        object ret = null;
        if (mi.Name == "InitializeSecurityContext") // For Client Mode
        {
            if (args[5] == null) // empty input, new connection
            {
                dynamic[] secbufs = (dynamic[])Activator.CreateInstance(miSDC_ASC.GetParameters()[6].ParameterType, new object[] { 1 });
                secbufs[0] = secbufalpn;
                object[] sdcargs = new object[] { 0, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4],
                    null,
                    secbufs,
                    args[6], args[7]
                };
                ret = miSDC_ISC.Invoke(null, sdcargs);
                args[0] = sdcargs[1];
                args[1] = sdcargs[2];
                args[7] = sdcargs[9];
            }
            else
            {
                ret = mi.Invoke(secchan, args);
            }
        }
        else if (mi.Name == "AcceptSecurityContext") // For Server Mode
        {
            dynamic[] secbufs = (dynamic[])Activator.CreateInstance(miSDC_ASC.GetParameters()[6].ParameterType, new object[] { 3 });
            secbufs[0] = args[2];
            secbufs[1] = secbufempty;
            secbufs[2] = secbufalpn;
            object[] sdcargs = new object[] { 0, args[0], args[1], args[3], args[4],
                null,
                secbufs,
                args[5], args[6]
            };
            ret = miSDC_ASC.Invoke(null, sdcargs);
            args[0] = sdcargs[1];
            args[1] = sdcargs[2];
            args[6] = sdcargs[8];
        }
        else
            ret = mi.Invoke(secchan, args);

        return new ReturnMessage(ret, args, args.Length, mcm.LogicalCallContext, mcm);
    }).GetTransparentProxy();
    
    // and set it, done
    fi.SetValue(null, result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET Core 2.1.2 includes the necessary changes to SslStream required to support ALPN. It isn't documented yet, but the pull request that adds it is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/24389)